# moxiemanager cannot upload jpeg files (No input file specified)

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, moxiemanager

Im using moxiemanager in my site and so far its working perfectly

it can upload jpg/gif/png etc

however im having trouble in making it upload jpeg images

i used this image to test it
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/86/Cactus_Flower_%28Easy-Macro%29.jpeg

when i try uploading it an error occurs that says "No Input File Specified"

[image]

this is how i made my code

```
$(document).on("click",".moxie_gallery",function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         moxman.browse({
            extensions: "*",
         });
     });
```

i also tried doing it this way

```
$(document).on("click",".moxie_gallery",function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         moxman.browse({
            extensions: "jpg,png,gif,jpeg",
         });
     });
```

by doing it this way, when i click on the Add Files button it does not show jpeg files

i checked the moxiemanager config and jpeg is included in the settings

```
$moxieManagerConfig['filesystem.extensions'] = 'jpg,jpeg,png,gif,html,htm,txt,docx,doc,zip,pdf';
```

can anyone point me in the right direction on how to make this work?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check your php.ini setting

upload_max_filesize = 100M (This should be more than you are triing to upload.)

If you use php-fpm restart the php5-fpm service too.